# If and Else sentences, on first click

Tags: javascript

Hi I made this simple animation, when you click on the animate button, the function does not work the first time but it works the second time, how can it be? And what is the solution?

```js
const fadeInOut = () => {
    const divElement = document.getElementById('demo');
    if (divElement.style.opacity == 0) {
        divElement.style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
        divElement.style.opacity = 0;
    }
};
```

```css
#demo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: burlywood;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="function.js" defer></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="demo"></div>
        <button onclick="fadeInOut()">Animate</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `.style` checks for an inline style, not the one you set in an external CSS file. You can go around this by setting an initial inline style to your element:

```js
const fadeInOut = () => {
  const divElement = document.getElementById('demo');
  if (divElement.style.opacity == 0) {
    divElement.style.opacity = 1;
  } else {
    divElement.style.opacity = 0;
  }
};
```

```css
#demo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: burlywood;
  display: block;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" style="opacity: 1"></div>
<button onclick="fadeInOut()">Animate</button>
```